# Image uploaded won't render in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have a function in my web application that lets you upload images, when I deployed the web app in my ec2 instance it won't render the image but saves in the folder

This is my ls -la in the upload folder

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 161841 Jul  3 08:06 image-1625299579523.jpg
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "render"? Render where? What do you do with the image after upload?

Comment: I'm sorry I upload it on my web application, it doesn't show in the frontend, but everything works in the backend like, saving the image and getting the directory. `/uploads/image-1625306170654.jpg`

Comment: 'Saving in the folder' is normally due to the web server not sending an appropriate `ContentType` with the file.

Comment: But it works when I use it locally, it just wont render when I uploaded it on the web server.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is I used the build folder in the web server instead of the public.